# Forcing SQL-scripts to be compatible with a specific Microsoft SQL Server version

Tags: sql, sql-server

During our development cycle we create migration-scripts that will be executed on multiple Microsoft SQL Server instances (on different servers).

Since these servers are being maintained by multiple third parties, we can't guarantee that all of them are using the latest Microsoft SQL Server version. For example, some of them are still stuck on 2008 R2.

Unfortunatly, this means that our SQL scripts must at least be compatible with 2008 R2 (and higher).

We would like to add an extra step to our build process (currently driven by MSbuild), which should check if all scripts are compatible with all versions of SQL Server that we should support (2008 R2 and higher). Both in terms of their syntax, but also in terms of built in functions (as an example, the CONCAT-function was only added in 2012).

However, we want to avoid having to install each supported SQL Server version and instead use only SQL Server 2017.

Note:

- I've had a look at compatibility modes in SQL Server, but when I set the compatibility level to 100, I seem to still be able to use SQL Server 2012 features like the CONCAT-function. Which doesn't surprise me, as I expect this to be intended for backward compatibility, rather than blocking features.
- These similar questions didn't really help either: [Using SQL Server Express 2008 with SQL Server 2005 database -how to check for compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225754/using-sql-server-express-2008-with-sql-server-2005-database-how-to-check-for-co), [How to check sql script compatibility agains SQL 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530306/how-to-check-sql-script-compatibility-agains-sql-2008)

Are there any other options?

Comment: [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) database projects can target specific versions; the build for them will generate warnings/errors as necessary when you're using features the targeted version does not support. It goes back as far as SQL Server 2005. (There is no separate target for 2008 R2 as opposed to 2008, but the differences there are minimal; you may as well target 2008.)

Comment: Note that installing "each" supported version is not really necessary; it's sufficient to install SQL Server 2008 R2 (Express) and test on that, in addition to SQL Server 2017. It is not absolutely, 100% true that that means the script will work on all intermediate versions as well, but it's close enough to the truth to be practical. MS is extremely reluctant to break backwards compatibility when not specifically permitted by the compatibility setting.

Comment: You can search for specific new features in your SQL Scripts using a SQL Script: SELECT o.name, o.type_desc FROM sys.sql_modules m INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id=o.object_id WHERE m.definition Like '%concat%'

Comment: @Jeroen SSDT is very interesting. However, our scripts (migrations) are currently being executed through RoundHousE.
I don't think it would be wise to migrate to using SSDT deployments, as it doesn't seem to handle data-migrations very well.
While we could still write our scripts in a SQL Server project, this approach doesn't seem very developer friendly.
Especially since we want the our Continuous Integration to not allow script-errors.

Comment: @GregViers I probably don't understand what you're suggesting, since I don't understand how this would help in a migration-script for example. It seems to be querying for objects that actually exist in the database.
Also, since we want our CI environment to not allow script-errors, I don't see how we could use this.

Comment: @Stanislas I have used this in a development environment to check for incompatible keywords before deploying. Not sure if it will work with your deployment process or not

Comment: @Stanislas: if SSDT is not an option, your best bet is an actual SQL Server 2008 instance. The reason is that to actually know if the script is using any unsupported feature, you need a fully engine compatible parser (to know when something is an identifier and when it's a keyword). SSDT has such a parser; anything outside MS would have its work cut out for it if you wanted to be certain about compatibility, and there's no real reason to trust the judgment of anything that's not an actual SQL Server in these matters.

Comment: From 2012 onwards, LocalDB is the easiest way to spin up an instance for testing/integration purposes, since it's equally simple to tear down. For 2008 and earlier, unfortunately, you're stuck with Express (or the Developer Edition if you must test/allow Enterprise features) and resetting that isn't possible beyond being careful that no script leaves stuff in the system databases.

Comment: Oh, last but no least: the T-SQL parser used by SSDT is available [separately](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom/) (at least, I think that's the one SSDT uses, I'm not 100% sure). By instantiating a parser class of the appropriate version (`TSql100Parser`) and letting it parse your scripts as part of the build, you should be able to have reasonable confidence that they will at least run on a 2008 instance (even though it does not test if they will really work at runtime). Personally, I'd still loop in an actual test server, at least in the deploy step.

Comment: I'm very intrigued by the suggestion of the Tsql100Parser.
Am I right when I say that this would only check the syntax and not the presence of features like the availability of built-in functions?
For example, recently a script failed because someone had assumed that the CONCAT-function was available in SQL Server 2008, while it was only introduced in 2012.
(I've updated my question with this example)

Comment: Fair point. No, for the specific case of `CONCAT` it doesn't work, at least not without more checking -- the parser simply recognizes this as an identifier, but does not go on to verify whether `CONCAT` exists. You'd need to have more logic to see that 1) this must be a system function since there's no schema prefix and 2) this system function isn't available in SQL Server 2008 R2. SSDT has such logic, but I don't think that specific logic is available in its own library. Even if it was, for *best* results you'd need to import the whole database -- `SELECT CONCAT FROM T` could be valid.